# Forcing refresh of a published Expo app

Tags: react-native, expo, exponentjs

could somebody explain how the Expo client decides whether to refresh my app or use the current version cached (~already downloaded) in the client?

When I'm pushing out a new version with `exp push`, the Expo app (on Android) doesn't seem to pick it up, unless I clear all data of the app.

I thought that bumping the `expo.version` in the `app.json` would solve this but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Ok, I understand it is supposed to happen automatically, but this doesn't seem so - I tried multiple devices which were not offline - I suppose there must be something obvious I'm missing...

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/offline-support.html#load-js-updates-in-the-background

Comment: I am not complete sure about this, but I think there are some api about manully update, and there are some about check version. Maybe we can make something during the app loading.

Answer (score 3):

Check that you **don't** have this option on the `app.json` file:

```
"updates": {
    "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
},
```

I had this option in there and it prevented the app from waiting for a new version to be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

(on Android) I succeeded by opening the app in Expo, I would see the cached version, then I force stopped the app intentionally, both the app and the expo client. This removes it from the list of open apps on the phone. 
Relaunched the expo client, then tapped my demo app again, and it loaded the new version. Tested a few seconds after publishing.